# Display category form fields in category page

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have added a new form field (i.e. excerpt) for category page and i saved the field value in database. Now i want to display the value in category page. Here is my code and may i know what went wrong?

```
function get_category_excerpt() {
    $cur_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    $cat_meta_data = get_term_meta($cur_cat_id,'category');
    return trim(html_entity_decode($cat_meta_data["excerpt"]));
}
```

I need to call the function and it is not a plugin. I used function_exists(), but i can't get output.

Comment: `get_term_meta` is not a wordpress core function, where does it come from ?

Comment: It comes from here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Taxonomy Metadata](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/) (as s_had_um said), your code should be :

```
function get_category_excerpt() {
    $cur_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    $cat_excerpt = get_term_meta($cur_cat_id, 'excerpt', true);
    return trim(html_entity_decode($cat_excerpt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak this code to display term value:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'get_category_excerpt' );
/**
 * Display details meta on Product Category archives.
 *
 */
function get_category_excerpt() {

    if ( ! is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $details = get_term_meta( $t_id, 'details', true ); //'details' is your term value

    if ( '' !== $details ) { //'details' is your term value
        ?>
        <div class="product-cat-details">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_kses_post( $details ) ); ?> //'details' is your term value
        </div>
        <?php
    }

}
```

You should be able to adapt this to make it work. Otherwise, here is the Source: http://www.wpmusketeer.com/add-a-wysiwyg-field-to-woocommerce-product-category-page/